# Can't set a variable to the value of a textfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield, double

I'm trying to get the text value of a `UITextField`, convert it to a `Double`, and save it to a variable. However, I'm getting the error:

> Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context.

What does that mean?

```swift
class SituationViewController: GBBaseViewController {
    // ....
    @IBOutlet var txtConsumption: UITextField!

    func fillValues(){
        let consumption = Double(self.txtConsumption.text) ?? 0 // the error happens here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `text` property of `UITextField` is an `Optional`, but the initialiser of `Double` needs a non-Optional `String`. Just provide a default value for the string.

```
let consumption = Double(self.txtConsumption.text ?? "") ?? 0
```

Comment: Or `let consumption = Double(self.txtConsumption.text!) ?? 0`. It's always safe to force-unwrap `UITextField text`.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, I also prefer force unwrapping `UITextField.text`, which is guaranteed to be non-nil, but some people still prefer non force unwrapping, so I used a default value instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func fillValues() {
    if let myText = self.txtConsumption.text { // Check if txtConsumption has a value
       let consumption = Double(myText) ?? 0
  }
}
```

The error happened because txtConsumption.text can be nil, Double need a no-nil parameter for initializer.

Comment: I think you meant to put `let consumption = Double(myText) ?? 0` on line 3